Cannot fetch data from backend in NestJS for NextJS frontend, despite CORS being enabled. What should I do?
I'm trying to connect my NextJS frontend to NestJS backend.
Here is my code for fetching (app\testpage\page.tsx):
async function handleClick() {
    const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:7777/api-json', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': '*/*'
      }
    } )
    const json = await res.text()
    console.log(json)
}

export default function TestPage(){
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>press to test</button>
        </div>
    )
}

Here is my code, enabling CORS (in main.ts):
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http:localhost:3000', 'http:localhost:3000/testpage'],
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type',
  });

Here is the error that I continue getting in the console:
Error in the console
Here's what I've tried:
app.enableCors();
  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type',
  });

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule { cors: true } );
I've also tried a lot of other solutions from StackOverflow, but none of them helped, unfortunatelly.

Neither http:localhost:3000 nor http:localhost:3000/testpage are valid Web-origin values. Retry with origin: 'http://localhost:3000' in your CORS configuration.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin

@jub0bs
Thank you for the advice! I changed the origin, but I'm getting a different error now:
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:7777/api-json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
And if I don't state access-control-allow-origin in request, I get the same error as before

Good, that's progress. This new error message indicates that you're including a header named access-control-allow-origin in your request. You can safely drop it  from your request, since that header is a response header, not a request header. More generally, there's no point in including headers whose name starts with Access-Control- in Fetch requests.

@jub0bs, thank you a lot for your help! It is true, that I shouldn't have used access-controll in Fetch request. I double checked the url, and it turned out, that I had api prefix in my url address, so I needed to access http:localhost:3000/api instead of http:localhost:3000. I deleted /api, so everything works now
